# IOS swift exception while saving in firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question. I want to save data into firebase database. this is my class:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseInstanceID

class ParamController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    var token = InstanceID.instanceID().token();
    var ref: DatabaseReference = Database.database().reference(token);

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        ref.childByAutoId().child("status").setValue(statusArray[row])
    }



    @IBAction func saveData(_ sender: UIButton) {

        ref.childByAutoId().child("age").setValue(myAge.value)


    }

}
```

xcode writes me:

> cannot use instance member 'token' within properly initializer;
>   properly initializers run before 'self' is available

I'm new to swift, I have coded on android. So I need to save this data under token.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a Swift default initializer cannot refer to the value of another property since at the time of initialization, the property doesn't exist yet.

To cope with this just use self.token with lazy initialisation:

```
lazy var ref : DatabaseReference =Database.database().reference(self.token)
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use instance member within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available.

So in order to initialize a property, we should use the init() methods i.e constructors.

For ex:-

```
var token = InstanceID.instanceID().token()
var ref: DatabaseReference
init() {
   ref =  = Database.database().reference(token)
}
```